# Best way to re-evaluate/update the truth value of a conditional expression passed as a class variable in Python

Tags: python, class, conditional-statements

In my code I would like to create an "event" class.  Upon initialization, an event is passed a condition for it to trigger.  I would like the flexibility to have any boolean expression passed as a trigger.  In simplest terms:

```
class event():
    def __init__(self,condition,outcome):
        self.condition = condition
        self.outcome = outcome

    def check(self):
        if self.condition:
             print(self.outcome)
```

Of course this is not quite right, because my intent is for the class to evaluate the original expression that was passed, and not its truth value at creation of the object.  For example:

```
foo = 0
e = event(foo != 0,"foo has changed value")
e.check()
foo = 1
e.check()
```

The desired outcome is for the check method to print a statement when it is called the second time.

I am open to reworking the whole class conception, but the main purpose of designing things this way is that the set of possible outcomes of an event is reasonably small enough to encode with a few class variables, and the triggering conditions will be known at instantiation but could vary widely and incorporate objects from a range of classes.

One last bit of info: all variables that will go into the conditional statement will have been instantiated before the event object creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass a callable instead of the actual bool value, like this (type annotations added for clarity):

```
from typing import Callable

class event():
    def __init__(self, condition: Callable[[], bool], outcome: str):
        self.condition = condition
        self.outcome = outcome

    def check(self):
        if self.condition():
             print(self.outcome)
```

Then you'd use it by passing a callable that returns a bool when you call it; an easy way to do this inline is via a `lambda`:

```
foo = 0
e = event(lambda: foo != 0, "foo has changed value")
e.check()
foo = 1
e.check()
```